# Call to a member function query() on a non-object WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to insert a new table row into a custom `wpdb` table. The data is coming from a form posted to a script.

I'm declaring `global $wpdb` at the start of the script, and inserting into the db, but for some reason it doesn't like the query function, which WordPress recommends to use in the codex.

```
// declare global wpdb
global $wpdb;

// set variables for posting to db
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

// post to the db
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        INSERT INTO $wpdb->entries
        ( name, email )
        VALUES ( %s, %s )
    ", 
    $name, 
    $email 
) );
```

Any ideas as to why it's bugging out?

Comment: what does var_dump($wpdb) says? And is this file included somewhere or includes something. It should be related to a file where $wpdb is actuall object

Comment: if I var_dump before the error, it just returns `NULL`

Comment: so it's not actual instance. Wordpress should have a config file where they declare `$wpdb = new someObject()...`, do you include this file, of is your file included by some of wordpress' inner files? Because if it's a standalone file, nothing will happen, $wpdb comes from nowhere

Comment: Ah! Including `wp-load.php` let it connect to the databse, now the var_dump shows the connection. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a wordpress feature, so the global `$wpdb` can be called only if it has been defined previously.

This means, inside the /wp-content/... folder if you use a script with wp specific features it won't work until it is compiled with wordpress core.

So, for example, a theme template or plugin files can work just by calling `$wpdb`, but your standalone script won't, even if it is inside the plugin or theme directory.

Simple solution is to include /wp-config.php file before running that script. Just write:

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-config.php' );
```

before calling `$wpdb`. It works for me.

Comment: I'd imagine this would work too. As mentioned in my comments including `wp-load.php` also did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: manisha
 * Date: 05-11-2015
 * Time: 15:30
 */
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-config.php' );
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

global $wpdb;
$result=$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "
             DELETE FROM wp_addemail
                 WHERE email = %s
                ",
        $email

    )
);

this things is worked for me
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my error using

```
  include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-config.php' );
```

This code actually I have submitted form data in my custom database table using Ajax but I have got a fatal error.. Now the fatal error is solved.